# How to assign a hotkey to Firefox container

Tags: firefox

I use Firefox Containers functionality. But I normally open new tabs using ctrl+t. How can I assign a hotkey to open a new tab in a particular container?

Comment: Did you mean docker container?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1396464/firefox-shortcut-to-open-a-particular-account-container

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Install the [Container Hotkeys](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/container-hotkeys) extension

After that you can open new container tabs with hotkeys:

- Windows/Linux: Open New Tab in Container - Ctrl + Alt + T Mac: Open
- New Tab in Container - Cmd + Option + T

Option 2:

Use [Easy Container Shortcuts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-container-shortcuts/)

It provides nine easy keyboard shortcuts to open new tabs on different containers: Ctrl+Shift+[1-9] / or Alt+Shift+[1-9] on OSx.