# Firefox shortcut to open a particular account container

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions, container

Firefox has [multi-account containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) that allow you to use the same website with several accounts, without having to use a different browser:

[image]

**Problem**: I always open tabs with CTRL-t because clicking takes too much time.

**Question**: How to open a new work-related tab with the fastest possible keyboard operation?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As of version 7 of the Containers extension, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> works without any further add-on. From the [release notes](https://github.com/mozilla/multi-account-containers/releases/tag/7.0.0):

> Set shortcuts in the add-on preferences panel: `Ctrl + Shift + {Num}`

Which containers correspond to which number can be configured in the add-on preferences.

As mentioned in other answers, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>tab</kbd> also works.

On MacOS it's <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+`{num}`

Comment: There's also Ctrl+Alt+1-9 that allows you to reopen the tab under a different container.

Comment: Not working for me, would be useful if it did.

Comment: my bad, I mistook the unmodified version with the addon called Easy Container Shortcuts.

Comment: For mac, use `Cmd + Shift + 1` through `Cmd + Shift + 9`

Comment: Per the [7.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/mozilla/multi-account-containers/releases/tag/7.0.0) you can configure which keybind opens which container. You can do this by going to the plugin settings in Firefox. You'll see a list of 10 keybinds with adjacent dropdowns listing your containers.

Comment: Yikes, this feature is really not there, yet. This doesn't consider the order _I applied_ to the different containers. Instead it seems to use the order in which containers were created. Not fun.

Comment: For Mac, only Cmd+Shift+1 and 2 work because the other Cmd+Shift+{num} keys are assigned to the OS for taking screenshots and those take priority over Firefox.

Answer (score 41):

According to the [Multi-Account Container plugin page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/), you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to open the panel. Then simply press the down arrow (or tab) and enter.

> `Ctrl + . (period)` keyboard shortcut is available to open the containers panel. You can then use tab and the enter keys to open new container tabs.

After Ctrl + . you can also use the numeric keys in order to select a container from the list. (Thanks cyberalex)

It doesn't seem to support opening a *specific* container with a designated shortcut.

Comment: After Ctrl + . you can also use the numeric keys in order to select a container from the list

Comment: @cyberalex Nice, I edited that into the answer.

Comment: Note if you have the extension pinned to the overflow menu, the numbers don't work until you press Tab twice

Comment: This is the better answer!

Comment: ... @cyberalex in order to select a container from the list, if you happen to have memorized in which order you created them. Because it doesn't go by display order with the numbering when using the shortcuts. Appears to be the order in which the containers were created.

Answer (score 7):

I use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-container-shortcuts/

AFAIK, there are no firefox built-in shortcuts

Answer (score 2):

expanding from @tone7 answer 
you could Ctrl + . (period) then use number to open corresponding tab

```
Ctrl + . + [1-9]
```

Comment: Same comment here: This doesn't consider the order _I applied_ to the different containers. Instead it seems to use the order in which containers were created.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do this natively with Firefox, but this extension seems to be doing what you are asking about: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-container-shortcuts/

According to the description:

> Provides nine easy keyboard shortcuts to open new tabs on different containers: Ctrl+Shift+[1-9] / or Alt+Shift+[1-9] on OSx. 
>   You can also open a new tab on the current container by pressing Ctrl (Cmd) + Alt + T

Comment: This is the same Firefox extension that is mentioned in the [currently accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1397467/90668).